# use one column 1 in table to sort colum2 and use column 1 as headings

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table with motor names and motor descriptions. There are are several motors with the same name as each other that have different descriptions.

```
Example:

motor_table


NAME       DESCRIPTION
Evinrude   90HP ETEC
Evinrude   150HP ETEC
Mercury    90HP 4/S
Mercury    150HP 4/S
```

I want to loop through the table and make an array for each of the different Names, but but I don't want the names to repete. So the motor name array would look like this.

```
$motor_names = array('Evinrude','Mercury');
```

Then I want to user the array to display the data in the table like this.

```
EVINRUDE
90HP ETEC
150HP ETEC

MERCURY
90HP 4/S
150HP 4/S
```

I've been at this for about an hour, but not having any luck.

Answer (score 1):

This query will give the result as comma separated then you can use explode function to parse the result,

```
SELECT NAME, GROUP_CONCAT(DESCRIPTION) AS description
  FROM motor_table GROUP BY name
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly then you can use a `GROUP BY` clause in your query:

`SELECT * FROM motor_table
GROUP BY name`

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit complicated, but you can do it in a SQL query:

```
select name
from ((select name, name as sort1, 0 as sort2
       from motor_table
      ) union all
      (select description, name as sort1, 1 as sort2
       from motor_table
      )
     ) t
order by sort1, sort2;
```

This actually doesn't have the blank line.  You can get that by doing:

```
select name
from ((select name, name as sort1, 0 as sort2
       from motor_table
      ) union all
      (select description, name as sort1, 1 as sort2
       from motor_table
      ) union all
      (select '', name as sort1, 2 as sort2
       from motor_table
      )
     ) t
order by sort1, sort2;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$array= array(
array('name' => 'Evinrude', 'description' =>   "90HP ETEC"),
array('name' => 'Mercury', 'description' =>   "90HP 4/S"),
array('name' => 'Mercury', 'description' =>   "150HP 4/S")
);

$motor_names = array('Evinrude','Mercury');
$data = array();
foreach($array as $row)
{
  $data[$row['name']][] = $row['description'];
}


print_r($data);

?>
```

use this code

OUTPUT:

```
Array ( 
         [Evinrude] => Array ( [0] => 90HP ETEC )
         [Mercury] => Array ( [0] => 90HP 4/S [1] => 150HP 4/S ) 
      )
```